# Interpreting GAM plots: gam.check()

Tags: regression, predictive-models, modeling, residuals, generalized-additive-model

I am new to building GAMs, and would appreciate any help interpeting the graphs produced by gam.check

I have written a gam model to predict probability of "success" in growing a species of kelp on an offshore kelp farm using presence / pseudo-absence data; my model is as follows

`gam7 <- gam(PA ~ nitrate + s(temperature, fx=FALSE, k=15) + s(salinity, fx=FALSE, k=25), data = alaria_df_strat_pa, family = binomial(link="logit"))`

[image: 1]

where presence=1 and absence=0; the model predicts a decimel ranging 0-1
The parameters only include those which apply to cultivation and thus do not include all variables which would naturally predict kelp distribution (ie water depth and light attenuation, as these do not apply on a cultivation site where all kelp is grown at an optimal depth)

I am having a difficult time interpreting the outputs from gam.check in a way which will help me improve my model equation - most concerning to me is the residuals graph which shows a very clear trend, and as well the distribution is not normal.

As well, I am unsure if the response vs fitted values graph can be explained by the predictor variable values I am inputting into my model being discrete (0,1) or if this is also cause for concern.

Are there any tips on how to go about analysing the graphs in a way which will help me understand what I need to do in order to improve my model? ie i can see there is a problem, but am perhaps lacking the analytical ability / statistical background to assess what exactly could cause the problem in a way which will help me to fix it.

[image: 2] [image: 3] [image: 4] [image: 5]